# Casting int type pointer address to char and printing it gives characters from right to left

Tags: c, pointers, memory-management, endianness

While working with DMA I came across the following code, result of which was somewhat unexpected for me:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main(){
    int *p=(int*)malloc(sizeof(int));
    
    *p=0x5E6A3D1B;
    
    unsigned char *q=(unsigned char*)p;
    
    printf("%X \n",*(q+1));
    return 0;
}
```

The result of the program was:
`3D`

When instead of printing `q+1` I only tried printing `q`, I got: `1B`.

Obviously while printing `q+3` I got `6A`.

**So, I have confusion that why the output I am getting is from right to left?**

**Is it because it is starting from the Least Significant Bit(LSB)?
If so then what is the reason**

Thanks a lot

Comment: This is "little endian" representation at work.  Read about ["endianness"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness).

Comment: We really need a good canonical dupe for "what is endianess". I can't find one.

Comment: Ok this spurred me to write together a "canonical dupe" self-answered Q&A over at Codidact: [What is CPU endianess?](https://software.codidact.com/posts/280640). Feel free to link it at SO too. Proof-reading is much appreciated as well.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how internally integer values are stored. They can be stored as big endian or as little endian. That is from the most significant digit or from the less significant digit.